# Variable is not defined in function

Tags: python

I'm currently working on the last function here, timeToRun.

I cannot figure out why I am receiving

```
 NameError: name 'caloriesBurned' is not defined
```

I'm attempting to calculate the number of minutes it would take someone of a certain weight to burn off a number of calories while running.

```
weight = (int(input("Enter your weight in pounds ")))
while weight <= 40:
        weight = int(input("Please reenter, weight must be higher than 40. "))

height = (int(input("Enter your height in inches ")))
while height <= 30:
        height = int(input("Please reenter, height must be higher than 30. "))

age = (int(input("Enter your age in years ")))
while age <= 1:
        age = int(input("Please reenter, age must be higher than 1. "))


def CalorieBurn(user_weight, user_height, user_age):
    calories = 655 + (4.3 * user_weight) + (4.7 * user_height) - (4.7 * user_age)
    print(calories)




def burnedRuns(user_weight):
    caloriesBurned = user_weight * .095
    print(caloriesBurned)


def burnedJogs(user_weight):
    caloriesBurned = user_weight * .0775
    print(caloriesBurned)


def burnedWalks(user_weight):
    caloriesBurned = user_weight * .054
    print(caloriesBurned)

def timeRequiredRun(caloriesDaily, user_weight):
    caloriesBurned = user_weight * .095
    timeToRun = calories / caloriesBurned
    print(timeToRun)

timeRequiredRun(caloriesBurned, user_weight)
```

Comment: you use this variable in `timeRequiredRun(caloriesBurned, user_weight)` but it is not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last line `timeRequiredRun(caloriesBurned, user_weight)` uses a variable called `caloriesBurned` which does not exist. I think you are looking for something like this:

```
def CalorieBurn(user_weight, user_height, user_age):
    calories = 655 + (4.3 * user_weight) + (4.7 * user_height) - (4.7 * user_age)
    return calories

def timeRequiredRun(calories, user_weight):
    caloriesBurned = user_weight * .095
    timeToRun = calories / caloriesBurned
    print(timeToRun)

calories = CalorieBurn(weight, height, age)
timeRequiredRun(calories, user_weight)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. One last thing. Can you elaborate on how I would format two files to separate the definitions from code that would import the definitions and then call on them?

Comment: You should open a new question for that as that is a completely different topic.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined caloriesBurned inside a function. This means it is only in that local scope and you cannot call it outside that function. You can use the `return` keyword to return that variable at the end of the function if you want, like `return caloriesBurned`. If you then set a variable as the function eg `var = func()` and the function had `return caloriesBurned` at the end then it will now be equal to the variable.

It appears that you have perhaps used the wrong variable in your call to `timeRequiredRun(caloriesBurned, user_weight)`. Maybe you have forgotten to ask the user how many calories they consume per day?